# Prevent artwork synch in iTunes for iPhone

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

I want to turn off my artwork synch!  I don't care if I have the artwork or not!  Is there a work around for doing this?  My phone always gets locked in a loop when synching and it is "stuck" on step 8 of 8 backing up artwork!

Comment: Deleting all artwork from iTunes would do the trick. Not syncing music would as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a bit of a clumsy workaround.

First you have to select all your songs on iTunes, right-click and select `Clear Downloaded Artwork`. Than you can sync your library with your iPhone. After that you can download your artworks again. So you have your artworks on your computer, but not on your iPhone.